# I am getting an SSL Exception - " java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address X.X.X.X found "

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, netflix-eureka, sslhandshakeexception, spring-webclient

I am having microservices in spring boot and using WebClient builder for different API to API call when I use @LoadBalanced in my application I am getting an SSL Exception - " java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address X.X.X.X found ".

SSL certificate CA is Go Daddy.

Kindly let me know how can I add SAN for IPAddress in my SSL CSR or how to avoid this error while using @LoadBalanced.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do not use HTTPS URLs where the hostname is an IP address, it will not work like you expect. Use real hostnames. While technically possible, it will be difficult to get a certificate with the IP address as SAN, or are you absolutely sure you own that IP and can prove it?

Comment: When I annotate my WebClient builder as @LoadBalanced then only it shows error otherwise it works fine.